# Asp.net MVC 3 many to many relationships create new item with jquery autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many, jquery-autocomplete

I am new to asp.net mvc and trying to create a simple web site.  There is a post with tags that have a many to many relationship.  I have read through the tutorial on [msdn](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) oh how to do the many to many  but i am not understanding it.  All i want to do is when creating a new post, have the ability to tag the post with keywords exactly like how creating a post works on this web site(stackoverflow).  I would like to have jquery auto-select on the Tags text box and then when the item is created the appropriate entries are made in the join the table.

So my questions are:

1. How to set up the jquery auto-complete on the tag text field
2. Ho to create a new post with the selected tags (in the join table)

I have seen several example that have many to many creates where you select the tags from a check box but that is not practical in this situation because there will be several hundred tags to choose from.

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class PostEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And the create controller(auto-generated):

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(post);
    }
```

The razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Post</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Tags</h3>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tags, new { @id = "NewTags" })
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a textbox as a multiselect item you would need a jquery plugin like [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Then you could have a viewModel like:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> relatedTags { get; set; }

//in the constructor you can initialize the list
// with all the tags available in your system
public PostViewModel()
{
        foreach (var tagin new dbContext().Tags.GetList())
        {
            Tags.Add(tag);
        }
}
```

}

Then in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PostViewModel post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Enumerate over the related tags selected from view 
        //and add the coincidences to the entity post.Post
        IEnumerator<String> it = post.relatedTags.GetEnumerator();
        while (it.MoveNext())
            post.Post.Tags.Add(db.Tags.Single(tag => tag.TagId == it.TagId));

        //Then you can save your changes to DB
        db.Posts.Add(post.Post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

And the View could be:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.relatedTags, new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "TagId", "Title"),
         new { data_placeholder = "Select related tags", style = "width:300px;", id = "relatedTagsToPost" })
```

where the id "relatedTagsToPost" is chosen initialized by:

```
$("#relatedTagsToPost").chosen();
```

That's All, it is not tested just adjusted from my project to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Vic's answer is a good solution but I prefer the Autocomplete jQuery plugin because you can also add new tags and not only select tags from a predefined or remotely loaded list...

take a look at:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Then, You have to edit a bit the code of your Controller, splitting the input tags by "," then saving them in the database.